# Regex: Matching HTML elements that do not contain specific text

Tags: java, regex

I need to strip out any movies that are not hosted by YouTube from html. Originally the request was to strip out any movies at all, for which

```
<object.*object>
```

worked pretty well. Now I basically need to do the same thing, but only if the stuff in the object tags is not hosted on youtube. I need a regex pattern that will match a string that starts with  but does not contain the word "youtube". There are probably more things I would need to consider if I needed this to work with all possible scenarios, but the above should do the trick for the job at hand.

I've been playing with negative lookaheads but have not yet been able to get it to work. Here are some of the things I have tried:

`<object.*(?!youtube).*object>` - matches all object tags since * is greedy

```
<object.+?(?!youtube).+?object>

<object(?!youtube)*object>
```

plus plenty of others that just further reinforce that I'm stabbing wildly in the dark at this one.

This is in Java 1.6

Comment: Please see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html before you go too far down this path. :)

Comment: Yeah the thought of pulling out a full blown parser seemed like overkill. There are really just small fragments and only a very small percent (< 3%) will have any videos in them at all. The thought of all the factories and classes Java would make me create hurts my brain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
(?s)<object((?!youtube).)*?object>
```

1. `(?s)` will cause the DOT meta character to match any character (including line breaks)
2. `<object` and `object>` must be clear
3. `(?!youtube).` will first check if no `youtube` can be "seen", and if this is the case, the regex will match any character
4. `((?!youtube).)*?` will match [3] zero or more times, reluctantly ("un-greedy")

Be aware that with regex, it is possible that things can go wrong. For a more robust solution, use a (x)HTML parser to iterate over all object tags and check if "youtube" exists in the attribute or inner-html you expect is to be.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that parsing the DOM or something would be better but in this very limited case I'm willing to flirt with the dark side.

Answer (score 0):

how about make it no so greedy? :) `<object.*?(?!youtube).*?object>`

Comment: No, that is not correct. Try it on `<object attr="youtube.com"></object>`